# Blackberry custom .KEY file not registered

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, blackberry-jde

I'm try to follow the guide on protecting PerstentObjects using ControlledAccess.

I hav created and imported a .KEY file into my project and selected the class to be protected.

Now, my problem arises when I try to sign the project. The signature tool tells me that my custom key is not registered.

How do I register it? Do I need a .CSI file to do this and if so, how to I generate it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved:

I needed to add the .KEY file into the source package in Eclipse and not just anywhere in the Eclipse project.